# How to implement multiple nested navigation in listview?

Tags: flutter, listview, routes, navigation, flutter-layout

So basically I have to implement a list with certain topics where each topic has a list of subtopics that is to be implemented on a different page and each sub-topic when clicked displays its respective display page. Now the list of topics and subtopics is huge...so is there any easier way to implement this navigation system rather than creating a new page for everything? Here's the code of the topic list I have created which takes data from the json format.

```
Expanded(
                      child: ListView.builder(
// scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                          itemCount: cryptoData.length,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            return Container(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 10, 16, 0),
                              height: 100,
                              width: double.maxFinite,
                              child: Card(
                                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                ),
                                elevation: 5,
                                child: Container(
                                  
                                  child: Padding(
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(7),
                                    child: Stack(children: <Widget>[
                                      Align(
                                        alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                                        child: Stack(
                                          children: <Widget>[
                                            Padding(
                                                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                                    left: 5, top: 5),
                                                child: Column(
                                                  children: <Widget>[
                                                    Row(
                                                      children: <Widget>[
                                                        cryptoIcon(
                                                            cryptoData[index]),
                                                        SizedBox(
                                                          height: 10,
                                                        ),
                                                        // Spacer(),
                                                        cryptoChange(
                                                            cryptoData[index]),
                                                        SizedBox(
                                                          width: 10,
                                                        ),
                                                        SizedBox(
                                                          width: 20,
                                                        )
                                                      ],
                                                    ),
                                                  ],
                                                ))
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                      )
                                    ]),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            );
                          }),
                    ),
```

And here's the json format

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CryptoData {
  static final getData = [
    {
      'image': "assets/images/card1.png",
      'change': 'English',
      'changeValue': '24 Chapters',
    },
    {
      'image': "assets/images/card1.png",
      'change': 'Moral Education',
      'changeValue': '32 Chapters',
    },
    {
      'image': "assets/images/card1.png",
      'change': 'Maths',
      'changeValue': '11 Chapters',
    },
    {
      'image': "assets/images/card1.png",
      'change': 'Hindi',
      'changeValue': '22 Chapters',
    },
    {
      'image': "assets/images/card1.png",
      'change': 'Computer Science',
      'changeValue': '10 Chapters',
    },
    {
      'image': "assets/images/card1.png",
      'change': 'Sanskrit',
      'changeValue': '103 Cards',
    },
    {
      'image': "assets/images/card1.png",
      'change': 'Social Studies',
      'changeValue': '12 Chapters',
    },
  ];
}
```

[image: diagram]

Answer (score 0):

If you are having huge list of data its better to implement different page with `ListView.builder` widget.

Comment: Could you please elaborate